# npm ERR! code E404, npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @XXXX

Tags: npm

I'm using a custom npm registry, and have recently started getting the following error happening when trying to do an `npm install`.

What could be causing this? I've tried different versions of node, and clearing my `node_modules` folder and neither helped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with trying to used scoped packages.

To resolve it, I simply hardcoded the dependencies by removing the `^` in the devDependencies list in `package.json`, e.g.

```
     "devDependencies": {        "devDependencies": {
-        "express": "^4.14.0",  +        "express": "4.14.0",
-        "gh-pages": "^0.12.0", +        "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
```

etc...